# Admob clang error

Tags: xcode, admob, clang

I run a clean and I am showing no errors but as soon as I run a build I get this error

ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have dropped the Admob files into my project and libGoogleAdMobAds.a is recognized as a linked library. I put in my code to pull up the add but I get that error.

The frameworks I have in use are

AdSupport,
StoreKit,
iAds,
SystemConfigure,
MessageUI,
AudioToolbox,
UIKit,
Foundation,
CoreGraphics.

I have removed all of these and then put them back. I removed Admob several times, deleted derived dependencies (got to try) I have completely removed the ad and got my app to build and run without Admob but as soon as I copy the Admob files to my app it stops building and throwing the error.

I have built a test app with Admob and it runs with no problems.

I hope someone can help as it is driving me to distraction, many thanks in advance for taking the time to help me.